# Performance problem in Flex using a heatMap

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, heatmap

I am using a heatMap in Flex 3.5 but I have a huge performance problem because I'm trying to set between 3.000 and 10.000 markers in the map. At the moment that the map begins the render process the Browser collpase.

The implementation that I'm using is a GoogleMpas one, created by "flex epiphanies" I used http://sunild.com/proto/Earthquakes2/Earthquakes.html as base.

Basically my implementation calls a service that calls a ZipCode latLon generator in the server side to calculate latLon of every registry that I have to show, that returns a big array (between 3.000 and 10.000 items) every item has a latitude and a longitude because I need to show every single mark.

The problem that I have is RENDERING the items in the Map, because the service that I'm calling is really fast.

I dont know if that is the best way to implement a heatMap but I'm sure that is not really efficient when the numbers of markers excced the 3.000.

I'll appreciate your support if anyone can give me suggestions or another heatMap implementation.3

Comment: Hard question, the issue is that your heatMap is probably not written using efficient algorithms. I believe you need to optimize the way it does tesselation...

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean exactly when you say you've to show every single mark? This thing you're trying to build would probably be helped with two kinds of optimizations:

1) Aggregate what you can server side. No need to leave that much processing to flash when the server can probably do it faster. If you don't literally need to show every point - and just need the heatmap itself - see if you can modify it to take an array of already aggregated marker counts, perhaps "chunks" in the range of several lats/longs square. If you're not showing some specific kind of information about each point, I don't think you'll actually have to "show every single mark". If you're pulling data straight out of some service you've no control over, perhaps you could make a simple middle layer just to aggregate the data before passing it to flash.

2) Optimize the heatmap functionality. If you know enough Actionscript I'd recommend porting the heatmap code to pure AS3 - and maybe the whole project if it's not too complex; for 10,000 pts you'll need a lot of the resources that the Flex framework will gobble up. If you're a crazy algorithmist, you'll probably see some other ways to optimize, but if not I'd just read a lot of posts by Grant Skinner (http://gskinner.com/blog) because optimizing actionscript is all that guy ever talks about.

I am doing something similar that will have to deal with points in the range of thousands to hundreds of thousands, and this is the approach i'll be taking.